# The same variable in Python Nested-loops has different IDs？

Tags: python, nested-loops

very simple Python code, but why the variable `n` has different IDs？ How can I implement this function to get `car`'s dictionary name?

```py
a = [{'a':['apple','animal']},{'b':['banana']},{'c':['class','car']}]
n = 0
while n < 3:
    print(id(n))
    for k in a[n].keys():
        if 'car' not in a[n][k]:
            n += 1
            print(id(n))
        else:
            print(k)
            break
    break
```

The result of the code is:

```
140720577618304
140720577618336
```

Comment: `n += 1` assigns a new object

Comment: You can ignore the `id()` of an integer. What is the problem you are having? What output do you expect?

Comment: `int` values are immutable. `n += 1` behaves exactly the same as `n = n + 1`, creating a new `int` (or getting a reference to a different `int`) from `n + 1` and assigning the result back to `n`.

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: The result of `id(i)` isn't the id of the variable `i`. It's the id of the variable `i`'s value. More precisely, it's the id of the object that the variable `i` references.  So if you do `j = 123`, then `i = j`, then `id(i)` will equal `id(j)`.  But if you assign a new value to `i`, then `id(i)` will change.

Comment: Thank you all, now I know the id() of variable is the id of the variable's value.

Comment: *Any* id is immutable... I don't understand what is your question here. Is it about the behavior of the `id` function, or how to implement the function? I don't see why the `id` is even needed here...

Comment: @Tomerikoo `id()` is just for testing the bug of my code, I used to think the failure of my codes is `n` can not be changed, so I use `id()` to identify `n` and got different IDs. Now, I have known I'm wrong, the mistake I made is put the wrong `break`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an integer in Python is immutable. By doing `n+=1`, you're not modifying the object called `n`, you're overwriting the name to point to a new integer object.

Comment: Thank you. Besides, @Tom Karzes explains more clearly for `id()`. The result of `id(i)` isn't the id of the variable `i`. It's the id of the variable `i`'s value. More precisely, it's the id of the object that the variable i references. So if you do `j = 123`, then `i = j`, then `id(i)`will equal `id(j)`. But if you assign a new value to `i,` then `id(i)` will change.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to search the lists for `car` and find which key has that list.

```py
a = [{'a':['apple','animal']},{'b':['banana']},{'c':['class','car']}]

for d in a:
    for k in d.keys():
        if 'car' in d[k]:
            print(k)
            break
```

Output: `c`

Comment: Thank you very much, this output is exactly what I want.

Comment: What really confuses me is the function of id(), now I have known it.

Comment: The `id()` function *can* be useful to check the id of an object for debugging purposes, but I would leave it as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

`id` is not what you are looking for. And when iterating through a iterable which you are not mutating, don't use a `while condition` or `for i in range(stop:start:end)`. Instead, you would want a `for i in iterable`. A one liner in your case could be

```
a = [{'a':['apple','animal']},{'b':['banana']},{'c':['class','car']}]
answer = [k for d in a for k in d.keys() if 'car' in d[k]]
```

output

```
['c']
```

Comment: Thank you. In above code I written, I attempt to change the `iterable` which is limited by `while`. It seems I put the wrong `break` in the last statement.

Comment: Glad to hear! if it helped consider accepting the post :)

Comment: I choose the answer that point out the actual function of `id()`, but I want to thank you anyway.